Length of minimum-weight walk in a complete graph
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple complete digraph with $n$ vertices and positive edge weights $d_{ij}, i\neq j \in V$. When the weights $d_{ij}, i\neq j \in V$ are metric (they satisfy the triangular inequality), then the length (the number of edges used in the walk; some edges may be counted multiple times) of the minimum-weight closed walk visiting all vertices is $n$, where the optimal walk is a Hamiltonian directed cycle.
If the weights are not metric, can we provide a tight upper bound on the length of the minimum-weight closed walk? I already found examples that show the bound is larger than $2n$.

In the asymmetric case, $$\left\lfloor \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right\rfloor$$ is a tight upper bound on the length of the minimum-weight closed walk that visits every vertex. (I would like to call this a "minimum-weight" and not a "shortest" walk, since the shortest walk ought to be the one with the minimum length.)
Let $W$ be some minimum-weight closed walk that visits every vertex of $G$, and let $L$ be the length of the longest segment of $W$ which is a path - that is, the longest segment which does not repeat a vertex.
Choose the starting point of $W$ so that it begins with a path of length $L$. Relabel the vertices of the graph so that $W$ begins with the path $v_0, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_L$, and so that the $i^{\text{th}}$ new vertex visited after $v_L$ is $v_{L+i}$.
For all $i \ge 1$, the segment of $W$ between the first visit to $v_{L+i-1}$ and the first visit to $v_{L+i}$ must be a path. If that segment were to visit a vertex $x$ multiple times, then the portion between the first and last visit to $x$ could be omitted with no loss - since, by assumption, between the first visit to $v_{L+i-1}$ and the first visit to $v_{L+i}$, the walk $W$ sees no new vertices it hasn't seen before.
By a similar argument, the segment of $W$ between the first visit to $v_{n-1}$ and the return to $v_0$ is a path. (At this point, we've seen all the vertices, and the only goal left is to return to $v_0$.)
So if we let "segment $0$" be the path through $v_0, \dots, v_L$, "segment $i$" be the path from the first visit to $v_{L+i-1}$ to the first visit to $v_{L+i}$, and "segment $n-L$" be the path from the first visit to $v_{n-1}$ to $v_0$, then these segments make up $W$ and each has length at most $L$. Altogether, the length of $W$ is $L(n+1-L)$, which has a maximum value of $\lfloor \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\rfloor$, obtained when $L = \lfloor \frac{n+1}2\rfloor$.
To show that this is tight, consider the following weights on our graph. Let $H$ be the directed graph with vertices $V = \{v_0,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ and the following edges:

Edges $v_0 v_1, v_1 v_2, \dots, v_{k-2} v_{k-1}$;
For each $i= k, k+1, \dots, n-1$, edges $v_{k-1} v_i$ and $v_i v_0$.

Then the shortest closed walk in $H$ that visits every vertex has length $(n-k)(k+1)$: we must visit all $n-k$ of the vertices $v_k, \dots, v_{n-1}$, and the shortest way to get from any one of these to any other is by going through $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_{k-1}$ as well each time. By setting $k = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$, we get the same length as before.
To turn this into a minimum-weight closed walk problem in a complete digraph $G$, simply set the weight of each edge to be $1$ if it is in $H$, and $n^2+1$ if it is not. This ensures that it is never worth it to use an edge which is not in $H$, so the minimum-weight closed walk in $G$ that visits every vertex is the shortest closed walk in $H$ that visits every vertex.

Thank you Misha! Great as always. Dose the bound decrease for the symmetric case? When the weights are metric, the length is the same for both asymmetric and symmetric cases.

For the symmetric case, I expect a bound of $2(n-1)$ but don't immediately see how to prove it. Certainly it is true that in an unweighted, undirected $n$-vertex graph $H$, the length of the shortest closed walk that visits every vertex is at most $2(n-1)$, and this is tight. Therefore there's no construction like the one at the end of my answer that will give any higher value, but that doesn't rule out weird trickery with weights.

Thank you! As it seems tricky, I just posted it as a new question.
